# How can I access a PDO connection from a different file?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I access a PDO connection(to mysql) in my class methods from a seperate file, without rewriting  a new PDO() every time I need the connection? And without using the singleton pattern - which is apparently frowned upon?

edit:
What I've done in the past was created a database class and in that class assigned a $connection attribute the connection via mysql_connect in a __construct method. In the same file, I would instantiate the class so that it was ready to go. Then whenever I needed that connection I would simply require that database file and add a global $connection in the method that need the $connection. I just can't figure out a solid way to accomplish this with new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

Comment: Related: [MySQLi class pattern for connection, close, leave open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312991/mysqli-class-pattern-for-connection-close-leave-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet is to store it in a variable with that is accessible globally.

Traditionally you'd store the variable in the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) namespace, though this is [frowned upon now a days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why).

Instead of using a `singleton`, what you should do is place the object into a [`registry`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) like [`Zend_Registry`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html).

Simply put, you just need to create a class with two static members; `set($key, $value)` and `get($key)`. When you construct your PDO object just call `set('db', $pdoConnection)` to store it and when you need to access the database, call `get('db')`.

Comment: what makes `Zend_Registry` different to `$GLOBALS['registry'][db] = $pdoConnection;`?

Comment: @hakre Its an object so it encapsulates the state of the registry. In theory you could add extra functionality (like logging) in the `get` and `set` calls. You can't do that with the vanilla $GLOBALS array.

Comment: Sure, put something into `$GLOBALS['registry']` with `ArrayAccess`, e.g. a write once, read many hash.

Comment: @hakre You should post this as an alternative answer. `ArrayAccess` seems like it would be a good base for a simple registry object.